# Animated graphs with matplotlib - can't sustain/append the annotation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot

I have an animated python graph. While I'm able to add an annotation (arrow) every time the counter can be divided by 100, I couldn't figure it out how to sustain the arrow (or append it) to the graph (see my screenshot). At the moment, the `add_annotation` works but only for 1 second and then it disappears (it should continued to be seen at least for another 10 seconds or so).

Paraphrased the example taken from [here](http://firsttimeprogrammer.blogspot.com/2014/12/animated-graphs-with-matplotlib.html)

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation 

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

z = np.random.normal(0,1,255)
u = 0.1
sd = 0.3
counter = 0
price = [100]
t = [0]

def add_annotation(annotated_message,value):
    plt.annotate(annotated_message, 
                 xy = (counter, value), xytext = (counter-5, value+20),
                 textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'bottom',
                 bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.1', fc = 'yellow', alpha = 0.5),
                 arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))

def getNewPrice(s,mean,stdev):
    r = np.random.normal(0,1,1)
    priceToday = s + s*(mean/255+stdev/np.sqrt(225)*r)
    return priceToday


def animate(i):
    global t,u,sd,counter
    x = t
    y = price
    counter += 1
    x.append(counter)
    value = getNewPrice(price[counter-1],u,sd)
    y.append(value)
    ax1.clear()

    if counter%100==0:
        print "ping"
        add_annotation("100",value)

    plt.plot(x,y,color="blue")


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,interval=20)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code, the main one is that you are clearing your axes at every step of the animation (`ax1.clear()`), and therefore you are removing your annotations.

One option would be to keep an array with all your annotations and recreate them everytime. This is obviously not the most elegant solution.

The correct way to do an animation is to create your `Line2D` object, and use the `Line2D.set_data()`, or `Line2D.set_xdata()` and `Line2D.set_ydata()` to update the coordinates plotted by your line.

Note that the animation function should return a list of artists that have been modified (at least if you want to use blitting, which would improve performance). For this reason, when you create an annotation, you need to return the `Annotation` object, and keep them in a list and return all the artists by the animation function.

This is quickly thrown together, but should give you a starting point:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation 

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax1.set_xlim((0,500))
ax1.set_ylim((0,200))

z = np.random.normal(0,1,255)
u = 0.1
sd = 0.3
counter = 0
price = [100]
t = [0]
artists = []
l, = plt.plot([],[],color="blue")


def add_annotation(annotated_message,value):
    annotation = plt.annotate(annotated_message, 
                 xy = (counter, value), xytext = (counter-5, value+20),
                 textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'bottom',
                 bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.1', fc = 'yellow', alpha = 0.5),
                 arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))
    return annotation


def getNewPrice(s,mean,stdev):
    r = np.random.normal(0,1,1)
    priceToday = s + s*(mean/255+stdev/np.sqrt(225)*r)
    return priceToday


def animate(i):
    global t,u,sd,counter,artists
    x = t
    y = price
    counter += 1
    x.append(counter)
    value = getNewPrice(price[counter-1],u,sd)
    y.append(value)
    l.set_data(x,y)

    if counter%100==0:
        print(artists)
        new_annotation = add_annotation("100",value)
        artists.append(new_annotation)

    return [l]+artists


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,interval=20,frames=500)
```